# Lenovo power management

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, power-management, thinkpad

I am trying to wake from sleep with a keyboard press on my ThinkPad P51. 
I have the latest Lenovo Power Management Driver installed. In the device manager, under Keyboards there is only `Standard PS/2 Keyboard` and no Power Management tab.

I recently reinstalled Windows 10 using the recovery usb provided by Lenovo. I also updated the BIOS using the provided [updater](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/jp/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-P-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-P51-TYPE-20HH-20HJ/20HH/20HHCTO1WW/PF0WUCY2/downloads/DS121296).

Are there additional drivers I need to install? What could be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did it work before?

Comment: Have you install Motherboard Driver and graphics driver from Lenovo official website?

Comment: Windows 10 clearly did not recognize the keyboard. Find the right driver on [Lenovo Support](https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/?menu-id=Technical_Support&menu-id=update_drivers)

Comment: I have installed all of the drivers for the ThinkPad P51 from Lenovo already.

Comment: Try GNU/Linux? :) https://askubuntu.com/a/72570